# Send message to a user when banned on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was moving my `client.on("guildBanAdd", function(guild, user){})` event to discord.js v13 from v12 but when user gets banned - it's not sending user a message, can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

#### code

```js
Client.on("guildBanAdd", function(guild, user){
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("You were banned from ${guild.name}!")
.setColor("Red")
.setDescription(text)
user.send(embed)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple, you just have to change `user.send(embed)` to `user.send({embeds: [embed]})` but please note that bot won't send a message if a user block messages from users who don't share any servers with them

Comment: This will not work. The user will not receive the DM because `guildBanAdd` triggers after the ban is added which mean the user won't be on the server anymore and for this reason does not share server with bot -> unable to send DM

Comment: @NotTrixxie if user don't block messages from bots they don't share servers with - bot will send a message. + User marked my answer as correct, so I think, I helped them

Comment: But bot can't send message if it does not share server with the user... There would be so many spam bots in Discord if every bot could send message to users that they don't share friends with @MegaMix_Craft

I'm not saying your answer is wrong but I'm saying that trying to send a message through the `guildBanAdd` event will not send it to anyone.. and will probably throw an error